# MVC3 URL Parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, parameters

I have some parameters in URL, which I would like to be present in the URL for all pages in my MVC3 app. For example:

```
mycompany.com/home?param=1 
mycompany.com/cart?param=1
mycompany.com/logout?param=1
```

Whether the user is navigating to a new page or submitting a form, how can I have my parameter 
be present in all my pages? Right now the only way I can think off is somehow reconstruct the URL for every new view I need to render. Is there built in functionality in MVC to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like something you should store in Session instead of updating all of your links to add the same parameter.

Comment: thx, can be done this way, but I am trying to find more native MVC solution. This is the answer I am looking for http://forums.asp.net/p/1746918/4718527.aspx/1?p=True&t=634587819228293082

Comment: If you're trying to take a pure MVC approach you might want to look at the reason for doing so. You're creating a maintenance nightmare for yourself. If you ever need to change it you have to find all instances where you added the parameter to the query string and update all of them. Miss one and you break something. Might I suggest at least creating a helper and always using that instead? At least then it is centralized. Another thought is that the query string is something the user can easily manipulate which could be a nuisance at the least and a security problem and the worst.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Session variable as the other poster suggested, or you could use a base view model which holds this static param value.

So your base view would be something like this:

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public static int ParamValue = 1;
}
```

then in each view model you use for each view, you'd have something like this:

```
public class PageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    // properties
}
```

This way, in each view, you can just reference @Model.ParamValue whenever you need to access it:

```
@Model Namespace.PageViewModel

My param value is <b>@Model.ParamValue</b>
```

Comment: Does this mean I have to update the URL with the parameter value, when I navigate to the next page?